# Multiple database connections class

Tags: python, mysql

This is my database connection class in order to handle multiple connections with the use of context managers. Brief explanation:

- The `__init__` method reads database configurations from an INI file in order to call the connection and set two dictionaries, one for connections and one for cursors.
- The `__enter__` method takes the specified database connection and cursor returning at the end the cursor to execute queries.
- The `__exit__` method commits the query and close the cursor if no exception has been identified.

I'm using [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) as MySQL module but I think that the code can be generalized for all MySQL modules, the functions are always those.

Any advice is welcome, I'm new with Python!

```
import os.path
import configparser
import pymysql.cursors

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()

        dbConfigFile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir, 'dbconfig.ini'))
        config.read(dbConfigFile)

        # Connections (database:connection method)
        self.connections = {
            'db1': self.connection(dict(config.items('db1info'))),
            'db2': self.connection(dict(config.items('db2info')))
        }

        # Cursors list (database:cursor method)
        self.cursors = {
            'db1': self.cursor(self.connections['db1']),
            'db2': self.cursor(self.connections['db2'])
        }

    def connection(self, config):
        return pymysql.connect(**config)

    def cursor(self, connection):
        return connection.cursor

    def __call__(self, database):
        self.database = database
        return self

    def __enter__(self):
        self.db = self.connections[self.database]
        self.cursor = self.cursors[self.database](pymysql.cursors.SSDictCursor)
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        if not exc_type:
            self.db.commit()
            self.cursor.close()
```

Usage:

```
db = Database()
with db('db1') as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM table_name")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neat idea! Some suggestions:

- `__exit__` should `try` to commit or roll back based on whether there is an unhandled exception, should then close the cursor, and should `finally` unconditionally close the connection. This is one of the main reasons for using a context manager - it is expected to always clean up after itself, leaving the relevant parts of the system in the same state as before using it.
- I would reuse the configuration section name as the keys in the `dict`. That way you don't need to maintain a mapping in your head or the code - what's in the configuration is what you get when you use the context manager.
- Rather than opening all connections and then using only one of them, it should open the connection and the cursor with the name passed in. Otherwise you're wasting resources.